# Appending a single point to a LineLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

How could the `LineLegend` be appended with the single black dot in the following graph?

[image]

```
Show[Plot[{Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, π}, Epilog -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5],Point[{π/8, Sin[π/8]}]},Frame -> True,FrameStyle -> Directive[Black],FrameTicks -> {{{-1, -0.5, 0, -0, 0.5, 1},None},{{0.0,π/4,π/2,π, 3 π/4,2 π},None}}, Axes -> {False, False},PlotLegends ->Placed[LineLegend[{"Sin", "x"}, LegendLayout -> {"Column",1},LegendMarkerSize -> 15], {0.2, 0.2}]],PlotRange -> {{0.0, π}, {-1, 1}},AxesLabel -> {x, "E"},LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

i.e., I want to make something similar to the following picture, where a single point has been shown in legends.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
options = {Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black],
   FrameTicks -> {{{-1, -0.5, 0, -0, 0.5, 1}, None},
     {{0.0, π/4, π/2, π, 3 π/4, 2 π},  None}},
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{0.0, π}, {-1, 1}},
   FrameLabel -> {x, Rotate["E", -π/2]}, LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}};
```

Several alternative approaches:

#### I.

Post-process `Plot` output to modify the legends:

```
appendToLegend[directive_, label_] := 
 ReplaceAll[LineLegend[a_, b_, c___] :> 
   LineLegend[Append[directive] @ a, Append[label] @ b, 
    Joined -> {True, True, False}, c]]

appendToLegend[Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]],  "Laughlin liquid"] @
 Plot[{Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, π},
  Epilog -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{π/8, Sin[π/8]}]},
  PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"Sin", "x"},
     LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1},
     LegendMarkerSize -> 15], {0.2, 0.2}],
  Evaluate @ options]
```

[image]

#### II.

Remove `Epilog` from `Plot` and use the point coordinates in `ListPlot` with the desired legend and combine the two plots using `Show`:

```
Show[Plot[{Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, π},
  PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"Sin", "x"},
     LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1},
     LegendMarkerSize -> 15], {0.2, 0.2}]],
 ListPlot[{{π/8, Sin[π/8]}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]],
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Laughlin liquid"}, {0.2, 0.2}]],
 Evaluate @ options]
```

[image]

#### III.

1. Append the automatic color list (i.e., `ColorData[97]/@{1,2}`) with the desired directive for the new legend item and use this list in the first argument of `LineLegend[...]`
2. Append the legend labels list with the desired legend label for the new legend item
3. Add the option `Joined ->{True,True, False}` in `LineLegend[...]`

```
Plot[{Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, π},
 Epilog -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{π/8, Sin[π/8]}]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[Append[Directive[PointSize@Medium, Black]][
     ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}],
    {"Sin", "x", "Laughlin liquid"},
    Joined -> {True, True, False},
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1},
    LegendMarkerSize -> 15], {0.2, 0.2}],
 Evaluate @ options]
```

[image]

#### IV.

1. Add a non-numeric function (e.g., `Null`, `blah`) to the function list in the first argument in `Plot`
2. Set the plot styles for the original functions as `Automatic` and, for the last one as desired (say, `{PointSize[Medium], Black}`)
3. Append the legend labels list with the desired legend label for the new legend item
4. Add the option `Joined ->{True,True, False}` in `LineLegend[...]`

```
Plot[{Sin[x], x, blahblah}, 
 {x, 0, π},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Directive[PointSize[Medium], Black]},
 Epilog -> {Black, AbsolutePointSize[5],  Point[{π/8, Sin[π/8]}]},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"Sin", "x", "Laughlin liquid"},
    Joined -> {True, True, False},
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1},
    LegendMarkerSize -> 15], {0.2, 0.2}], 
 Evaluate @ options]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Show[Plot[{Sin[x], x}
  , {x, 0, π}
  , Epilog -> {
    Black, AbsolutePointSize[5]
    , Point[{π/8, Sin[π/8]}]
    }
  , Frame -> True
  , FrameStyle -> Directive[Black]
  , FrameTicks -> {{{-1, -0.5, 0, -0, 0.5, 1}, None}
    , {{0.0, π/4, π/2, π, 3 π/4, 2 π}, None}
    }
  , Axes -> {False, False}
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[{ColorData[97][1], ColorData[97][2], White}
     , {"WC", "M=2 bubble", "Laughlin liquid" }
     , LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}
     , LegendMarkers -> {"", "", 
       Graphics[{Black, Disk[Scaled[{0, 0}], {0.75, 0.75}]}]}
     ]
    , {0.7, 0.4}
    ]
  , PlotRange -> {{0.0, π}, {-1, 1}}
  , FrameLabel -> {x, Rotate["E", -π/2]}
  , LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]